# Как правильно писать в телефоне сообщения

Tags: грамотная-речь

Завтра, то  хоть будешь в офисе?

Answer (score 4):

Здесь "то" частица, будет писаться через дефис и без запятой: Завтра-то хоть будешь в офисе?

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно в предыдущем ответе, можно только добавить:

1) ТО - частица, употр. для  выделения,  подчеркивания;

2) ХОТЬ - усилительная частица уступительного характера со значением ПО КРАЙНЕЙ  МЕРЕ,

В результате получим словосочетание  "завтра-то хоть", которое имеет дополнительное смысловое значение уступки  (сегодня не пришел, а завтра-то хоть придешь?)+ выделение + усиление.

Вот такая у нас речь разговорного стиля - краткая, точная и выразительная.

Answer (score 1):

Завтра**-то** хоть будешь в офисе? Вот это правильный вариант =) Как уже было сказано выше, в данном случае "то" есть частица, а частица, как известно, пишется через дефис.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с Надюшкой. Это единственно возможное написание.